# Android LinearLayout start putting items from the right

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make a Linear layout which has 2 items, one item is an arrow and needs to fit on the right of the screen, the other item is an edit text that needs to fit the rest of the view.  I have tried a bunch of ways to do this but none of them seem to work.  My latest attempt is to use layout_weight but that is giving me issues of the arrow has too much area around it on bigger phones.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sendLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scale_5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/scale_10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width='0dp'
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            >


            <com.heyjude.heyjudeapp.customview.EditRobotoRegular
                android:id="@+id/editChatMsg"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/linear_back"
                android:hint="Type your message..."
                android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|text"
                android:textColor="#5f6060"
                android:textColorHint="#5f6060"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ivSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like as it currently is, as you can see there is too much space around the arrow

[image]

Comment: use weight 10 in `EditRobotoRegular` ...... and after that it will coming same then you have to post your whole xml .Bcoz it may be problem due to othew `VIEW`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one... and change the icon and text according to your requirements

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="#cfd8dc"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type your message"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This will look like this]